# Array items count

Tags: php, arrays

from an API im getting data in a format like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [project_id] => project:4f7008b82ec51dfe4c13c77ab857ae53
            [amount] => 1.000000
            [price] => 1170.000000
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [project_id] => project:4cc47cf864f7a85d4c13c77ab857ae53
            [amount] => 3.000000
            [price] => 49.000000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [project_id] => project:4cc47cf864f7a85d4c13c77ab857ae53
            [amount] => 1.000000
            [price] => 450.000000
        )

)
```

My code looks like this

```
  foreach($results as $req){
        $request = $SimplicateApi->makeApiCall('GET' , '/projects/service?&q[project_id]='.$req['id'].'&q[invoice_method]=Subscription&select=price,amount');

        foreach($request as $item){
            print_r($item);
        }

}
```

I want to check if all the prices within an array (summed up) are larger than 250 then echo 'Larger' for example.

The first array is 1170.000000 since its the only one i dont need to sum it up with anything else so it passes since its larger than 250

In the second array i have multiple prices , so i would need to sum up 49 + 450. Again larger than 250 so its a pass.

How can i best do this?

Comment: That doesn’t change the fact, that you are asking way too broad. Coming up with some basic steps to at least _try_ and solve this, would be mainly _your_ responsibility. Once you have something to show, we can help with with that, if you can’t manage to get it done properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `$totalPrice` you can summing each `$item['price']` and check if the `$totalPrice` is larger than `250`

```
$totalPrice = 0;
foreach($request as $item){
   //print_r($item);
   $totalPrice += $item['price'];
}

if($totalPrice>250){
  //Is larger.
}else{
  //Is not larger.
}
```

Comment: Will the total price keep increasing in the next round or will it reset back to 0 on the next round?

Comment: @Kevin.a Define _next round_.

Comment: The next array @vivek_23

Comment: you mean the next `$request`? depend if you need to sum all requests or just one by one.

Comment: @Kevin.a So are the 2 arrays in your post inside another big array? If yes, please edit your post to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @vivek_23 they're standalone arrays , they are not in a big array. Im just trying to see if the totalPrice will be of value 0 every "request"

Comment: @Kevin.a Yes, it does in the first statement `$totalPrice = 0;` and would work just fine if you put it in a function.

Comment: If you declare `$totalPrice = 0;` inside `$result for` then **yes**

Answer (score 1):

Non-loop method:

Documentation for [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) is not very difficult.

```
$price = 0;
array_map(function($project) use (&$price) { 
  $price += (float) $project['price'];
}, $request);

if( $price > 250 ) {
  echo "it's greater";
} else {
  echo "it is not greater";
}
```

Basically take the array request and map it; You link it back to a `$price` variable looking at the original variable and alter its value. Instead of creating a new variable within the `array_map` function.

Within it just make sure to cast the `float` to make sure the addition will add as a number and not concatenate as a string. Look up `type juggling` [on PHP's docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a reduce version:

```
$totalPrice = array_sum(array_map(function($item) { return $item['price']; }, $request));

$passed = ($totalPrice > 250) ? true : false;
```